# Organizing multiple Docker containers with large configurations

Tags: docker

I have a series of tools I use for CI/CD, error-tracking, logging, data collection, etc, which are all available as Docker images. These are all independent, not part of any project repo or anything, just general tools deployed on a tooling server.

I'm still pretty new to Docker, so apologies if this is something that should've come up early, but I'll explain the situation I'm trying to rectify.

**Tools within containers:**

- Fider
- Sentry
- Drone
- Prometheus

Lets use **Drone** as the example, in order to start my drone container I'd use the following from the commandline:

```
docker run \
        --volume=/var/lib/drone:/data \
        -e DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
        -e DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
        -e DRONE_RPC_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
        -e DRONE_SERVER_HOST=drone.xxxxxxxx.com \
        -e DRONE_REPOSITORY_FILTER=xxxxxxxxxx, \
        -e DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http \
        -e DRONE_USER_CREATE="username:codespent,admin:true" \
        -p 8884:80 -p 4431:443 \
        --restart=always --detach=true \
        --name drone drone/drone:1
```

This starts the drone container with my specified configuration, but lets say I need to replace the container to add some configuration, for example we'll change the `DRONE_SERVER_PROTO` to `https`. So currently what I'd do to achieve this is stop the container, remove the container, then run the above `run` command again. This doesn't feel right, and with an array of tools & configuration options this just really isn't sustainable.

My question is pretty general, but I'd like to know how to manage these containers and configurations in a manageable way. I've tried creating systemd units, and this was slightly better, but still I feel I'm missing something more obvious.

Ideally I don't want whomever is working on these tools to have to memorize the configuration, I'd like it to persist somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is very broad, I can only advice you to watch Docker Compose first, this is really the must-have (aka. describing containers in text) and open the gate to git versionning for them (and therefore CI / CD)

Take also a look at Portainer to ease your burden as this is a very popular tool to have a GUI to operate your containers, volumes and images.

Regards,

Comment: As I hate the answers not starting by a greeting, I am sorry and say "Bonjour" to you, kind reader